# making columns of different sizes in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, subplot

I am new to Bokeh and am trying to make a layout of 3 columns which have different amount of plots. For example, column 1 has 3 plots, but column 2 has 4 plots. So far the only way I can do it is by padding the shorter columns with extra entries, but this is obviously a waste of space.

I saw in [this example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html#general-grid-layout) that is is possible to do w/ rows of different sizes, so I hope one can do so w/ columns...

Comment: Are you talking about *layout* columns? Or *data* columns in a column data source? The former can be whatever, there are no restrictions. The latter has to have all data columns in a CDS be the same length (it is analogous to a DataFrame in that respect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this by composing your layout using the `row` and `column` methods from the layouts module. Here is an example of what that could look like:

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

my_layout = row(
    column([plot1, plot2, plot3]),
    column([plot4, plot5])
)
```